# Bower is not updating via npm update -g bower

Tags: npm, bower

When I just installed bootstrap-css with `bower install` I got this message to update bower from 1.2.8 to 1.3.1

```
$ bower install bootstrap-css
-----------------------------------------
Update available: 1.3.1 (current: 1.2.8)
Run npm update -g bower to update
-----------------------------------------
```

So I ran it and this is what happened

```
$ npm update -g bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower

$ bower --version
1.2.8
```

I'm still on `1.2.8`. How come `bower` is not updating?

Comment: Maybe you should remove bower and install it again.

Comment: Yes that is what I did and it worked. https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5248#issuecomment-45222702 Not an elegant solution though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems updating bower to the latest version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585790/problems-updating-bower-to-the-latest-version)

Answer (score 17):

You need to update bower by running the following command:

```
npm install -g bower@latest
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Weird that running exactly what they tell you to run doesn't actually work!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command

```
npm update bower -g
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly npm update -g bower was updating my bower to the latest but when I was checking the version with bower --version, it showed me the old version. I removed the old package from .npm/bower/ and then it recognized the new version!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having this problem on Windows and has Visual Studio 2015 installed, you will need to go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External` and rename `bower.cmd` to `bower.cmdBAK`.

Before doing that, running `bower --version` was always returning `1.3.9` for me when I knew from running `npm ls -g | grep bower` that I was at `1.6.5` globally.