# Unable to update Bower - to use Polymer

Tags: bower, bower-install

I'm unable to update Bower. I've tried following the instructions on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585790/problems-updating-bower-to-the-latest-version) but to no avail. I managed to update node without issue.

Thanks in advance.

```
System info:
Bower version: 1.2.7
Node version: 0.10.29
OS: Darwin 13.2.0 x64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please perform a full manual uninstall as described [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5248#issuecomment-45222702). Pay attention to follow each step carefully. This is a bullet-proof solution to your problem.