# Why is Bower returning a 410 error message?

Tags: bower

Recently my bower tasks have been failing and returning a 410 error message like below:

> 2017-10-11T13:22:21.2226829Z bower angular-cookies#v1.6.7-build.5456+sha.3651e42
>   EINVRES Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-cookies failed with 410
>
> 2017-10-11T13:22:21.2706832Z ##[error]Bower failed with error: C:\NPM\Modules\bower.cmd failed with return code: 1

I haven't actually changed anything in this project I'm just spinning up a new instance in a test slot. Does anyone know why this has started happening?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is because bower has changed the registry url today without a redirect.

The preferred method is to update bower:

```
npm upgrade -g bower
```

However if you are unable to do so for whatever reason you can edit your .bowerrc file to include this to point to the new url.

```
{
     "registry": "https://registry.bower.io"
}
```

Comment: It's not a recommended solution. Recommended solution is to update bower (npm install -g bower)

Comment: I deploy to Heroku which downloads bower as a dependency. I had an "exact match" version in the package.json which caused this issue for me. Answer got me there!

Answer (score 7):

You need upgrade your bower.

```
npm upgrade -g bower
```

Please take a look for upgrade solutions [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585790/problems-updating-bower-to-the-latest-version)